# How to get DatePicker data into the body of an email

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uidatepicker

I have some text fields that are filled out and then used to populate the body of an email with NSString.  I have done the same code as I have for the text fields for the date picker but its not a string that gets outputted so NSString doesn't work. I have tried using NSDate but am not sure how to get this in like the others.  This is the code:

Delaring the variables:

```
 @interface HomeView ()<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtClient;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtTime;
    IBOutlet UITextView *txtNotes;
    IBOutlet UITextView *txtHardware;
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *txtDate;
}
@end
```

populating an email:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:[userDefault objectForKey:@"Subject"]];

    [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[userDefault objectForKey:@"Email"]]];


    NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Client: %@\n Time: %@ \n\n Notes: \n %@ \n Hardware: \n %@",txtClient.text,txtTime.text,txtNotes.text,txtHardware.text];
    txtClient.text = @"";
    txtTime.text = @"";
    txtNotes.text = @"";
    txtHardware.text = @"";
    [picker setMessageBody:string isHTML:NO];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{

    //Not working - input date data
    //NSDATE *string=[NSString stringwithformat:@Date: %@",txtDate.date];
    //txtDate.date = @"";

    }];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your specific problem? Do you not know how to get the date from a date picker, or how to convert that date to a string?

Comment: In a giant moment of noob on my behalf i hadn't thought to convert it to a string.. So, the problem would be converting it from a date into string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]; // this is the date format, you can also use    [NSDateFormater setDateStyle: ] and [NSDateFormatter setTimeStyle: ];
 NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:DATE ]; //replace DATE with your date object
```

If using `setDateFormat:` visit [this](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) page to see what all the letter code are.

If you're using `setDateStyle:` these are all the options and what they'll look like

```
   NSDateFormatterNoStyle     = no style
   NSDateFormatterShortStyle  = “11/23/37” or “3:30 PM”.
   NSDateFormatterMediumStyle = “Nov 23, 1937” or “3:30:32 PM”.
   NSDateFormatterLongStyle   = “November 23, 1937” or “3:30:32 PM PST”.
   NSDateFormatterFullStyle   = “Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD” or “3:30:42 PM Pacific Standard Time”.
```